# React Native Swift callback

Tags: javascript, swift, callback, react-native

I would like to send a String to a Swift-implemented module from React Native and then just get a String result as a callback from the native module for further use.

Here's what i've got:

```
//HelloWorldModule.m

#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(HelloWorldModule, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(sayHelloWorld:(NSString *)name callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock *)successCallback)

@end
```

Alongside the Swift implementation:

```
//  HelloWorldModule.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

@objc(HelloWorldModule)
class HelloWorldModule: NSObject {

  @objc func sayHelloWorld(name: String,  callback successCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
    NSLog("Log from Swift: \(name)")
    successCallback([name])
  }
}
```

and finally whatever goes into the ReactNative part:

```
// requiring the Swift module in React Native
var HelloWorldModule = require('react-native').NativeModules.HelloWorldModule;

...

// using it somewhere in the render function

render: function() {
       return (
        <Text>
          Hello World Module answers: {this.hwmExt("Jadzia Dax")}
        </Text>
       );
},

hwmExt: function(name) {
    return HelloWorldModule.sayHelloWorld(name, function(result) {
       var hwAnswer = "swiftCB: " + result;
       console.log(hwAnswer);
       return hwAnswer;
    });
}
```

The line `console.log(hwAnswer);` prints out what I expect it to be `swiftCB: Jadzia Dax` but the result is not being passed over? Did I do something wrong in the method definition in Swift as I always get undefined? Somehow got blind over this problem :/ React Native Swift module callbacks are unfortunately not covered in the RN docs, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `RCTResponseSenderBlock` callback follows Node.js *error first style* i.e. the first callback param holds *error* and the second param holds *result*.

In your example, you are returning a value for *error*, and no value *result*, hence `undefined`. You should return `NSNull` as the error (first) parameter, and `name` as the second param e.g. `[NSNUll(), name]`.

[This short blog post](http://carminedimascio.com/2016/01/create-a-react-native-custom-swift-component/) shows exactly how to do this using Swift and React Native. In the [blog](http://carminedimascio.com/2016/01/create-a-react-native-custom-swift-component/) post, see line **11** in `MySwiftThingy.swift`.

Comment: Great find, short and sweet article!

Comment: @cmd please have a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620105/dismiss-a-view-controller-from-react-native I am trying to dismiss a react component presented from an Objective-C module.

Comment: only update to the blog is you have to add an underscore as such simpleMethod(_ message: String)

Comment: Goddam, two days trying to make it work with a successCallback and an errCallback. Thank you so much